# How to add a row to a dataframe and avoid "non-numeric argument to binary operator"

Tags: r

I have a dataframe. I want to normalize columns 2 and 3 by dividing them by the maximum value of column 2 and 3.

```
> testdf<- data.frame("a"=c("b",2), "b"=2:3, "c"=3:4, "d"=4:5, stringsAsFactors = F)
> testdf
  a b c d
1 b 2 3 4
2 2 3 4 5

> testdf[2:3]<-testdf[2:3] / do.call(pmax, testdf[2:3])
> testdf
  a         b c d
1 b 0.6666667 1 4
2 2 0.7500000 1 5
```

Notice how the df contains a mix of numerical and string values?
Now I want to add a row with more data. If the first element of the added row is a string, the code gives an error.

```
> testdf<- data.frame("a"=c("b",2), "b"=2:3, "c"=3:4, "d"=4:5, stringsAsFactors = F)
> testdf
  a b c d
1 b 2 3 4
2 2 3 4 5
> testdf<- testdf %>% rbind(c("a",6,7,8))
> testdf
  a b c d
1 b 2 3 4
2 2 3 4 5
3 a 6 7 8
> testdf[2:3]<-testdf[2:3] / do.call(pmax, testdf[2:3])
Error in FUN(left, right) : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

If instead I use only numerical values, it works.

```
> testdf<- data.frame("a"=c("b",2), "b"=2:3, "c"=3:4, "d"=4:5, stringsAsFactors = F)
> testdf
  a b c d
1 b 2 3 4
2 2 3 4 5
> testdf<- testdf %>% rbind(c(5,6,7,8))
> testdf
  a b c d
1 b 2 3 4
2 2 3 4 5
3 5 6 7 8
> testdf[2:3]<-testdf[2:3] / do.call(pmax, testdf[2:3])
> testdf
  a         b c d
1 b 0.6666667 1 4
2 2 0.7500000 1 5
3 5 0.8571429 1 8
```

Any help to why this happens is greatly appreciated. I need to be able to add rows that contain text and numbers while keeping the code working. My guess is that I'm messing up types but I couldn't figure out, how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `rbind(c("a",6,7,8))` you are effectively doing `rbind(c("a","6","7","8"))` thereby making everything in `testdf` character. This is because a vector (`c(...)` or individual columns of `testdf`) can hold data of only one type and `R` will try to do so while accommodating all data. In this case, `character` would store all data but `numeric` would get rid of the letters for example.

Just use `testdf %>% rbind(list("a",6,7,8))` instead of `testdf %>% rbind(c("a",6,7,8))`.

Compare the output of `list("a",6,7,8)` vs that of `c("a",6,7,8)`.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `add_row`

```
library(tibble)
testdf <- add_row(testdf, !!!set_names(list('a', 6, 7, 8), names(testdf)))
testdf
#  a b c d
#1 b 2 3 4
#2 2 3 4 5
#3 a 6 7 8
```

Now, do the `pmax` on the numeric columns

```
testdf[2:3] / do.call(pmax, testdf[2:3])
#          b c
#1 0.6666667 1
#2 0.7500000 1
#3 0.8571429 1
```

Comment: @Joram It is for evaluation as we are passing a named `list`